# Error when querying relation data from parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have loaded a list of users from Parse into a listview and want to add checkmarks to the users who are related, using the below code:

```
private void addFriendCheckmarks() {
    mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null) {
                //list returned- look for a match
                for (int i = 0; i < mUsers.size(); i++) {
                    ParseUser user = mUsers.get(i);

                    for (ParseUser friend: friends) {
                        if (friend.getObjectId().equals(user.getObjectId())) {
                            getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It seems to be working in terms of checking the check marks, however I am getting an error:

> 05-03 06:17:43.095    2776-2776/com.example.app I/MainActivity﹕ test6
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.105    2776-2808/com.example.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.112    2776-2776/com.example.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabc804d0, tid 2776
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.116    2776-2776/com.example.app D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.142    2776-2808/com.example.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.143    2776-2808/com.example.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.147    2776-2808/com.example.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.152    2776-2808/com.example.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf80b770, tid 2808
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.172    2776-2808/com.example.app I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.221    2776-2808/com.example.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.241    2776-2808/com.example.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>
> 05-03 06:17:43.241    2776-2808/com.example.app W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf808f20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>
> 05-03 06:17:46.275    2776-2776/com.example.app E/ExploreFragment﹕ java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

I've spent a couple of hours trying to work out at what point a string is being cast to a JSONObject here but can't figure it. I would like to understand what is causing this error and what I can do to avoid it.

Comment: can you please post the full logcat?

Comment: thanks, have edited the post as requested.

Comment: Ah, no need the log above of the error... need the log below `ClassCastException`. There are many lines started from "at" and must be "cause" which usually shows the #line where this error occurred. So with this info easy to detect problematic place.

Comment: anyways, if problem in current code. try to make `String friendName = friend.getObjectId();` and `String userName = user.getObjectId();` and compare them with `equalsIgnoreCase()`. Clean and rebuild. From given above code I don't see anything else.